# Edit values of a select list in a view

Tags: views

I have a select list in a `view` that filters the `view` by the team number.

Each team number will be displayed in the select list like:
`2014-2015 - 01`, `2014-2015 - 02` and so forth.

All I want are the last two numbers to display on the view's table, so what I did was used a computed field to just grab the last two numbers so then only the team number shows up.

However, I can't use a computed field to automatically fill the contents of a select list, and when I create a team filter, the select list has  `2014-2015 - 01` , `2014-2015 - 02`, and so forth.

**I want to edit the select list so it only shows `01, 02,` etc.**

I am really good with `JS injector` and prefer to do most things like this with that, but sadly the page is refreshed so many times it's not a good thing to use.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a custom module and in `hook_form_alter` according to your expose filter module `form_id`  get your form element,then you can change the value of your expose filter without change the value of them (as what you want)
something like below code can help you

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id){
   if ($form_id == "your_views_exposeform") {
            // first try dpm($fom); to see what you have there
            foreach($form['expose_your_field']['und']['#options'] as &$item){
            //  repalce label of select option items with what you want
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: How do I edit a single entry in the list?  I can get back each value with $item, but I'm not sure how to edit that value so it changes in the array.

Comment: @Matt tell me about what you want to change?
add one of item array key and index in your question

Comment: I ended up using javascript in a custom module and that did the trick.

Comment: @Matt just dpm($item) and see what you have there then try to change it according what you want